Hibernate envers not auditing changes on one to many relationship
Recently I faced the need to implement an audit log for changes on database. I need to audit which columns were changed, who made that changes and when it happens. I decided to use Hibernate envers like an old project did and now I'm facing the following issue:
The project itself contains a lot of tables, but there are two of them that are demanding a bit of attention: Users and Groups.
I'll list an example
class User {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JsonManagedReference
  @Audited(withModifiedFlag = true) // added by me
  List<UserPermission> userPermissions;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JsonManagedReference
  @Audited(withModifiedFlag = true) // added by me
  List<Group> userGroups;
}

class UserPermission {
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "User_ID", nullable = false)
  @JsonBackReference
  @Audited // added by me
  User user;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userPermission", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JsonManagedReference
  @Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
  List<UserPermissionScope> scopes;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userPermission", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JsonManagedReference
  @Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
  List<UserPermissionFilter> filters;
}

UserPermissionScope property will associate a permission with scope that is a simple object that contains a named action that an user can perform: "CREATE, EDIT, LIST, VIEW".
UserPermissionFilter will filter which resources a user can perform this action: User is a resource, for example.
Explaining this, the problem I'm facing is the following:
For an existing user, if I assign this user to a group, then envers understands that this is a direct change on user entity and then save a log.
When I assign a permission for a User, the same happens.
But when I edit a permission, envers doesn't log anything because it understands that this wasn't a direct change on User and nothing happens.
Edit permission means I'll add a filter or a scope to an existing user permission, and this isn't logged on database.
Is there a way to propagate a change made on another entity relaed with User? Like, if I edit UserPermission I need to audit changes on User too.
I'm expecting to check if it is possible to audit changes on oneToMany relationships.
OBS: This is an existing database. These tables already exists.

Try making UserPermission @Embedded component instead of @Entity

I'll check how this will affect database. I'm dealing with an existing database and this is a legacy project and it's been complicated to audit what I need.

If you cook it right @Embedded can do all you need, except, maybe, generating id.

I forgot another restriction: you cant query @Embedded directly, you have to query parent entity. In return you can get rid of link to parent entity from it,
